# how to send a variable from php to a .sh file

Tags: php, ubuntu

Is it possible to send a variable from a php script to a shell script??
The code is given below"

exec('./test.sh');

I want to send a variable called $path to test.sh file.and recieve this variable in test.sh file and want to use this value.so how do I get the value in that test.sh file..Is there have any solution for that..??
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can pass variables the same way as you do on the commandline. Just append them. For safety, escape the variable before you do so:

```
exec('./test.sh ' . escapeshellarg($path));
```

Then, in your shell sccript, this is available as `$1`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that:

**Pass as argument to the script:**

```
<?php
exec("./test.sh ". escapeshellarg($path));
```

And from the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Path is $1"
```

**Pass through the environment**

```
<?php
putenv('PATH='. $path);
exec("./test.sh");
```

And from the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$PATH"
```

**On the standard input**

I guess there is a way to do this too, but I wasn't able to find out how on a quick search.

Comment: it's probably best not to overwrite `$PATH`

Comment: I know, but he *wanted* to overwrite `$PATH`.. don't know if intentionally or unintentionally.. (the first time I read the question, I understood that he wanted to set a custom `$PATH` for the script, but maybe I was wrong..)